# I am trying to call questions from my mysql and show them in ajax pagination in php

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am using ajax to call the questions from my mysql table to show them in pagination form but i am having trouble calling them according the subject and category and show them in the pagination form. 
Here is my code .

```
        <?php
    print_r($_GET);
    //echo $_GET['val12'];
    $X=$_GET['val12'];
    $category=$_GET['catg12'];
    //print_r($_GET);

    ?>

    <?php
    //session_start();
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
    include "admin_panel/$classname.php";
    }
    $obj = new connect();
    $st=$obj->con();

    $user= new questionclass();
    $results=$user->getQuestions($_POST);
    //print_r($_POST);
    extract($_POST);

    //$_SESSION['category']=$category;

    //$key_id=$_SESSION['key'];

    $qry = "select * from categories where category_name='$category'";
    $run =mysqli_query($st,$qry);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run);

    $testname=$row['test_name'];
    $subject_name=explode(',', $testname);


    ?>
    <div class="loading-div"></div>
    <div id="results"><!-- content will be loaded here --></div>
    <?php

    { //include config file
        //Get page number from Ajax POST
        if(isset($_POST["pagenum"])){
            $page_number = filter_var($_POST["pagenum"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); //filter number
            if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');} //incase of invalid page number
        }else{
            $page_number = 1; //if there's no page number, set it to 1
        }
        $item_per_page=3;   
        //get total number of records from database for pagination
        $results = $st->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM question");
        $get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
        //break records into pages
        $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

        //get starting position to fetch the records
        $page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
        //echo $page_position;

    foreach($subject_name as $values ) {

        $values=trim($values);

    }




        //Limit our results within a specified range. 
        $sel = $st->prepare("SELECT quesname, answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4,correctanswer FROM question where category_name ='$category' && subject_name ='$X' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");
        $sel->bind_result($quesname,$answer1,$answer2,$answer3,$answer4,$correctanswer); //bind variables to prepared statement

        $sel->execute(); //Execute prepared Query

    //$qrey=mysqli_query($st,$sel);
    //print_r($sel);
    $x=1;

    while($rowin=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel)){


        //Display records fetched from database.
        echo '<ul class="contents">';
        while($sel->fetch()){ //fetch values
    ?>
    <div class='cont' id="<?php echo $x;  ?>">
    <?php
     echo "<div  id='question_splitter_$x'>";?>
                <div id='subject_name<?php echo $x;?>' >
                                <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $x;?>"> <?php echo $x?>.<?php echo $rowin['quesname'];?></p>
                                <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>'/><?php echo $rowin['answer1'];?>
                                <br/>
                                <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>'/><?php echo $rowin['answer2'];?>
                                <br/>


                                <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>'/><?php echo $rowin['answer3'];?>
                                <br/>

                                <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>'/><?php echo $rowin['answer4'];?>
                                <br/>


                                <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="smart_quiz" id='radio1_<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $rowin['id'];?>'/>
                                <br/>
                                </div>
    </div>

    <?php



            echo '<li>';
            echo  $quesname. '. <strong>' .$answer1.'</strong> &mdash; '. '. <strong>' .$answer2.'</strong> &mdash; '. '. <strong>' .$answer3.'</strong> &mdash; '. '. <strong>' .$answer4.'</strong> &mdash; '.$correctanswer;
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        echo '<div align="center">';
        /* We call the pagination function here to generate Pagination link for us. 
        As you can see I have passed several parameters to the function. */
        echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
        echo '</div>';

        exit;
    }
    }
    ################ pagination function #########################################
    function paginate_function($item_per_page, $current_page, $total_records, $total_pages)
    {
        $pagination = '';
        if($total_pages > 0 && $total_pages != 1 && $current_page <= $total_pages){ //verify total pages and current page number
            $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination">';
            $next           = $current_page + 1; //next link
            $right_links    = $current_page + 3; 
            $previous       = $current_page - 3; //previous link 

            $first_link     = true; //boolean var to decide our first link

            if($current_page > 1){
                $previous_link = ($previous==0)? 1: $previous;
                $pagination .= '<li class="first"><a href="#" data-page="1" title="First">&laquo;</a></li>'; //first link
                $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$previous_link.'" title="Previous">&lt;</a></li>'; //previous link
                    for($i = ($current_page-2); $i < $current_page; $i++){ //Create left-hand side links
                        if($i > 0){
                            $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }   
                $first_link = false; //set first link to false
            }

            if($first_link){ //if current active page is first link
                $pagination .= '<li class="first active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }elseif($current_page == $total_pages){ //if it's the last active link
                $pagination .= '<li class="last active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }else{ //regular current link
                $pagination .= '<li class="active">'.$current_page.'</li>';
            }

            for($i = $current_page+1; $i < $right_links ; $i++){ //create right-hand side links
                if($i<=$total_pages){
                    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$i.'" title="Page '.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
            if($current_page < $total_pages){ 
                    $next_link = ($i > $total_pages) ? $total_pages : $i;
                    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" data-page="'.$next_link.'" title="Next">&gt;</a></li>'; //next link
                    $pagination .= '<li class="last"><a href="#" data-page="'.$total_pages.'" title="Last">&raquo;</a></li>'; //last link
            }

            $pagination .= '</ul>'; 
        }
        return $pagination; //return pagination links
    }

    ?>

before using pagination i was using this code to call all the question

$sel="select * from question where category_name='$category' && subject_name='$X'";
$qrey=mysqli_query($st,$sel);
print_r($sel);
$x=1;
```

This is the query for getting the category and the subject from the page.

Comment: Are you truing in Wordpress ?

Comment: no why is there some code problem?

Comment: Feels more like AJAX/JS (frontend) issue rather than problem with your backend PHP code. Please specify what problem exactly are you facing. Do the questions load on page load? Does it load next page when you click on next link etc.?

Comment: I have created three  in my page which would get the subject name from the mysql then i have use the ajax on the click event of those tabs so there is a div which is showing the question in the tabs using ajax. but when i implement ajx pagination code with my questions query it shows error  "while($rowin=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel))" at this point that the sel is passed as an object .

Comment: "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given" this is the exact error